# How to add collection.liquid to an existing page?

Tags: shopify, liquid

In Shopify, I'm trying to take the template `collection.liquid` and render it in another page, just like embedding it. But i'm not sure how to accomplish that.

```
{% paginate collection.products by 50 %} 
{% include 'breadcrumb' %}
{% if settings.show_sort_by and collection.products_count > 1 %}
  {% include 'collection-sort' %}
{% endif %}
{% if current_tags.size > 0 %}
<h1>{{ current_tags.first }}</h1>
{% else %}
{% endif %}
{% if collection.description.size > 0 %}
<!--START HERO-->

<!--END HERO-->
{% endif %}
<!--START PRODUCT GRID-->
<section class="product-grid twelve columns alpha omega">
   <div id="collection_hero" class="collection_hero_class">
  <img src="http://carnegie.org/fileadmin/Media/News/press_releases/whitehouse.JPG"> 
  </div>
  {% if collection.products.size > 0 %}
    {% for product in collection.products %}
      {% include 'product-grid-item' %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
    <p id="no-products" class="animated fadeInUpBig">There aren't any products in this collection!</p>
  {% endif %}
</section>
<!--END PRODUCT GRID-->
{% include 'paging' %}
{% endpaginate %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to do the same thing and kept getting errors.

Fixed it by making a new **Snippet** called *list-collections* and copying everything from **list-collections.liquid** into that. Then made a page template called *page.list-collections.liquid* and pasted this code into that before /div:  **{% include 'list-collections' %}**

Then, I made a new page using the **page.list-collections template**, and entered my introductory text, images etc in that, which displays above product collections on the page when published :)

Answer (score 0):

Copy everything that's in `collection.liquid` and paste it into a new snippet (let's say you call it collection-copy.liquid).

Then, in the page you want to add the collections page to, just add `{% include 'collection-copy' %}`

That should just dump everything that's in collection-copy.liquid and output it to your page.

Comment: thanks. when i do that i'm getting a "Liquid error: Array 'collection.products' is not paginateable" error. any ideas?

Comment: @rs202 I haven't run across that problem myself, but this page recommends using `collections[settings.frontpage_collection].products` instead of `collections.products`
https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/liquid-error-array-collection-products-is-not-paginateable-115061
Maybe that'll help?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do so is to :

- Create a new page template for example : page.list-collections
- Then place under : `{{ page.content }}` this line :

  {% section 'list-collections-template' %}

Now create a new page in Shopify then select the new page template.
Normally you should be able to add new collections in the "Customize" section of your page !